# What is the real meaning of having multiple entries in the LL(1) parse table?

Tags: compilation, compiler-construction

For the Grammar :

```
S->aABb
A->a/epsilon
B->b/epsilon
```

This grammar is not `LL(1)` but this grammar is Unambiguous, so even after having multiple entries in the table, this grammar is Unambiguous. So, what is the intuitive meaning of having multiple entries in the table when the grammar is Unambiguous.

When the parser visits the column `M[B, b]`, it has 2 choices `B->b` and `B-> epsilon`. This nature is not non-deterministic but this grammar is unambiguous in reality so how to resolve this conflict wherein although we are having multiple entries in the parsing table still the grammar is Unambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the grammar is not LL(1) and you'll either need to use another parsing algorithm or rewrite the grammar to be LL(1) if possible (which in this case would just mean switching the `b` and the `B` in the `S` rule).

Comment: But multiple entries imply ambiguity right but it is not ambiguous , so is it ambiguous only in case of LL(1) , it can be parsed by any other bottom up parser .

Comment: @radhika Multiple entries imply that the grammar is not LL(1) and nothing more.

Comment: But doesn't LL(1) checks for ambiguity using the rule : First(Non-terminal) intersection Follow(Non-terminal) = empty set ?

Comment: @radhika No. Checking whether a grammar is ambiguous isn't part of implementing an LL(1) parser at all. You need to check whether the grammar is LL(1) (or rather you'll find out naturally when building the parse table), but not whether it's ambiguous. Any grammar that's LL(1) is also unambiguous. And if the grammar isn't LL(1), it doesn't matter whether that's because it's ambiguous or left-recursive or because of the amount of lookahead required. It's not LL(1), so you can't use it.